# Calling conventions and Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, calling-convention

How can i express a calling convention in `assembly` language like one can the higher level languages like `C++` (by using the `__cdecl`/`__stdcall`/`__fastcall` prefixes in function definition)?

Comment: What do you mean by “express?”

Comment: Note that you are much more likely to receive helpful answers if you address the comments people write.  Ignoring them won't do you any good.

Answer (score 1):

Languages like C++ need calling conventions so that the compiler can generate the correct code for the call. In assembly language you write argument passing, function call and stack cleanup explicitly. You dont need them in function definition.

Comment: So if the standard c __printf__ function is said that passes arguments using the stack does it just mean that the __printf__ definition have a __cdecl/__stdcall prefix?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Calling convention says the compiler how to pass arguments (stack, registers, etc) and who clears the stack - the caller or the callee.